# Cannot mount NTFS volume; fixntfs doesn't resolve the problem

Tags: mount, ntfs

I am trying to mount a USB harddrive with NTFS.  Ubuntu displays this eror message:

[image]
`sudo fixntfs` didn't resolve the problem.

```
linuxcomprrrr@rr-a-computer:/home/rrrr# sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdd1
Mounting volume... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x1ba0a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x1a60a
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x1ba0a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x1a60a
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... OK
Failed to load runlist for $MFT/$DATA.
highest_vcn = 0x1ba0a, last_vcn - 1 = 0x1a60a
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
linuxcomprrrr@rr-a-computer:/home/rrrr#
```

How can I fix the volume from Ubuntu?

Comment: Don't think you can. You have to use Windows to fix the filesystem, and in case of a hardware fault, you need to replace the device.

Comment: Linux user still needs Windows to fix disks? This is unfortunate :(

Comment: Not sure what did you expect. There is no magic linux command that can fix all filesystem errors and all hardware faults.

Comment: @Victor Forest Windows still doesn't support ext4 at all. Shame.

Comment: @jdwolf There is a [driver](http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/) for Windows.

Comment: @mikewhatever My point is that microsoft does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

ntfsfix can only do basic NTFS repair tasks. It's main functionality is marking the file system dirty so that Windows will automatically scan it.